# Database strategies for Phonegap offline application

Tags: database, json, cordova, mobile

I must develop a mobile application for all mobile platforms using phonegap. it will be a kind of medicine information application.but i am new on phonegap. firstly app will store user informations (it is not an obligation, maybe i wont do that but it may be good for statistics), but later app would just search and show up medicine information. The problem is that which database method i should use to provide these information locally and later how can i update it when needed? I found different strategies but not exactly the one i need.
I will be appreciated if you can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use HTML5 web storage(local storage, session storage) to store user information and for database you can use phonegap storage api.if you want to update information then you have to do regular database syncing means when your application will be in foreground use javascript intervals to update database tables.If you need more help let me know.
you can sync all medicine infromation from server database to local database using ajax.
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html
Thanks & Regards
Jitendra Kumar